# How to read array of objects in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, key

I have the next code:

```
var datos = [{id: 10, precio: 20, cantidad: 1},
{id: 2, precio: 20, cantidad: 1},
{id: 3, precio: 20, cantidad: 1}];
```

How can I acces to specific value? Or how can I set a key to each object? Because I can't acces to a specific value, only if I use $.each or the index of the object. To make this more simple, I want some like this:

```
 var foo = datos["key"];
 var bar = foo.id;
```

And I don't want this:

```
var foo = datos[0];
var bar = foo.id;
```

Thank you, and sorry for my bad english. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check you the find function in lodash. You'll be able to find the element based on a property without knowing its index in the array.